# Getting parent child relationship of a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict as below to show the relationship of group of companies hierarchy.

```
dict = {}

dict["A"] = ['Company A']
dict["B"] = ['Company B']
dict["C"] = ['Company C'] # This can be removed if necessary
dict["D"] = ['Company D']
dict["E"] = ['Company E'] 
dict["F"] = ['Company F'] # This can be removed if necessary
dict["G"] = ['Company G'] # This can be removed if necessary
```

Now I have parent child relationship between these root level elements (Company's)For an example one company may control several companies.
Key C is the parent of key A & B.(Company C owns company A and B)
Key F is the parent of Key D & E.
Finally the Key G is the parent of C & F.

I need to create a new dict as follows or create a new dict which shows below.Can this parent child relationship can be handled dynamically and get below output.How to have that parent child relationship so that it is possible to update the relationship and update the output.

```
{'A': ['Company A'],
 'B': ['Company B'],
 'C': ['Company A', 'Company B'],
 'D': ['Company D'],
 'E': ['Company E'],
 'F': ['Company D', 'Company E'],
 'G': ['Company A', 'Company B','Company D', 'Company E'],
}
```

Could someone share the code that I can create this.

Comment: Is that structure supposed to be within the actual dictionary parent/child relation? If so, can you provide a better example illustrating the described case? i.e. `Key C is the parent of key A & B` and so on

Comment: @yatu I will update the problem to get more understanding

Comment: You can also think of using classes with inheritance and instances of this classes instead using dicts, directly *(or subclassing dict itself)* to implement your custom behaviour.

Comment: You might want to use a tree structure

Comment: you can do it by playing around dict.keys() and dict.values() but first start decalring parent-child relationship and apply it using dict values and dict keys

Comment: also dict["A"] = ['Number A'] does not make sense and this is not dict syntax, it should be dict = ["A" : "Number A"] , show me exactly how your dict looks like

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have another dictionary or other structure mapping parents to their children, you can define a recursive function to get all the "leafs" for the different keys. If the tree is larger, you may want to use `functools.lru_cache` to memoize and reuse past partial results.

```
from functools import lru_cache

d = {'A': ['Number A'], 'B': ['Number B'],
     'C': ['Number C'], 'D': ['Number D'],
     'E': ['Number E'], 'F': ['Number F'],
     'G': ['Number G']}

is_parent_of = {'C': ['A', 'B'], 'F': ['D', 'E'], 'G': ['C', 'F']}

@lru_cache(None) # optional, for caching
def get_leafs(x):
    if x in is_parent_of:
        return [z for y in is_parent_of[x] for z in get_leafs(y)]
    else:
        return d[x]

print({x: get_leafs(x) for x in d})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply create another dictionary where all parents and their children are defined into and simply loop over the current dictionary and if you found that there is any key that match with any key in the parents dictionary the results dictionary should inherit its  values.

talk is cheap let me show you some code

### Example

```
dictionary = {}
dictionary["A"] = ['Number A']
dictionary["B"] = ['Number B']
dictionary["C"] = ['Number C']
dictionary["D"] = ['Number D']
dictionary["E"] = ['Number E'] 
dictionary["F"] = ['Number F']
dictionary["G"] = ['Number G']

parents = {
    'C': ['Number A', 'Number B'],
    'F': ['Number D', 'Number E'],
    'G': ['Number A', 'Number B','Number D', 'Number E'],
}

res = {}

for x, y in dictionary.items():
    if x in parents.keys():
        res[x] = parents[x]
    else:
        res[x] = y

print(res)
```

Comment: But G is not (direct) parent of A, B, D, and E but of C and F

Comment: @tobias_k I just use an expected output to generate this answer